# jQuery X-Editable validate with running HTML code

Tags: javascript, jquery, validation, bootstrap-modal, x-editable

I use [X-Editable jQuery plugin](https://vitalets.github.io/x-editable/), and my validating looks like this:

```
validate: function(value) {
    if ($.trim(value) == '') {
        str = '<font color="red">' + LNG_7 + "<br />" + "second line</font>";
        return str;
    }
};
```

My problem is, that the X-Editable escaping the HTML code while validation. If I turn the escaping option on, it not works with validation. I need run the HTML code. Anyone help? Thanks.

Comment: Welcome. Please [take the tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) to make the best use of this network.

Comment: Why are you switching quotation mark type (from single to double)? I'd stick with one.